# Shortest Path w/ ability to destroy set number of obstacles

Tags: path-finding, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have a programming assignment to find shortest path from START to GOAL in a "Sector". You can visualize the Sector as a 2D array of Nodes with one node being START and another node being GOAL. All other nodes are either FLAT or HILL. You cannot travel over hills. For example:

```
  0123456789
 |----------| {S = START, G = GOAL, " " = FLAT, # = HILL}
0|S         |
1|#####     |
2|          |
3|          | 
4|          | 
5|          | 
6|          | 
7|          |
8|   #######|
9|         G|
 |----------|
```

Ok, so I implemented Dijkstra's Algorithm to come up with the shortest path from S to G. But there's an additional problem that I cannot figure out, and I would appreciate some suggestions. We are given 5 bombs to blast away HILLs if it let's us find a shorter path. So for the example Sector I posted, I would want to use 2 bombs to get a path like this:

```
  0123456789
 |----------| {S = START, G = GOAL, " " = FLAT, # = HILL, + = PATH}
0|S         |
1|#+###     | Blasted away HILL @ [1][1]
2|  +       |     4 bombs remaining
3|   +      | 
4|    +     | 
5|     +    | 
6|      +   | 
7|       +  |
8|   #####+#| Blasted away HILL @ [8][8]
9|         G|     3 bombs remaining
 |----------|
```

Sectors given to test the program are 100x100 and have thick "Mountain Ranges", so with only 5 bombs, you can just blast a straight line to the goal or anything.

Any ideas on how to calculate when you use bombs, intelligently? Right now, I have a temporary implementation that just says "if the node you are currently looking at is a HILL and you have bombs left, blast the HILL". Obviously that's not going to cut it, but I can't think of how to do it properly.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your first solution you have a graph connection you had a graph connecting only the Flat spaces. I propose you to create high cost edges to each Hill. Each incoming edge to a Hill cost for example 100000 units. All other edges costs 1 unit (just an example).

In your first example, you could have an edge between `(0,0) -> (0,1)` with a cost of 100000.

So, you'll need to stop the search (in Dijkstra, if the cost the search of the adjacent nodes) if the accumulated cost is greater than or equal to `(bombs + 1)*100000`.

The basic idea is that your algorithm will try to minimize the cost, and using a bomb is an very expensive. Naturally, the shortest path will find the path with the least bombs. If you have 5 bombs in the minimum path, then the cost will be 500000 plus the cost of the traveling through the Flat terrain.